# How to delete backup files using a bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, delete

I want to automatically delete the backup files(those ending with ~) from everywhere on my computer.

I tried to write a simple script using`locate` command, but I'm stuck at deleting file having space in there name, like this

```
/home/abc/def/Unnamed Document~
```

Can you provide a script to delete backup files(considering that some of them have space in there name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/find.1.html) instead:

```
find /some/path -name '*~' -type f -delete
```

- `-name '*~'` for filenames ending in `~`
- `-type f` for regular files (skipping directories, etc.)
- `-delete` ... well?